# Datepicker and timepicker not working on appended elements

Tags: jquery

I'm using `datepicker` and `timepicker` for my fields like this:

```
<input class="datepicker" name="sugg_date[]" type="text" value="" />
<input class="tp" name="sugg_time[]" type="text" value="" />
```

I'm also using this function to add more rows:

```
<script>
    function add_next_row(e, row_a) {
        curr_row = $(row_a).prev('p');
        curr_row.append('<input class="datepicker" name="sugg_date[]" type="text" value="" />');
        curr_row.append('<input class="tp" name="sugg_time[]" type="text" value="" />');

        if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            e.returnValue = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

But the new rows don't work with the `timepicker` and `datepicker`. Can someone please tell me why.

Comment: $('.datepicker').datepicker();
      $('.tp').timepickr().timepickr({convention:12});
this is how i use jquery to apply the timepicker and datepier

Comment: U have to reload datepicker after inserting new row so at the end of function call datepicker one more time

Comment: how can I do that I'm kind of new to this

Comment: where is your code where you called the datepicker function and the timepicker function????

Comment: by juqery 

 $(document).ready(function(){
      
        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
        $('.tp').timepickr().timepickr({convention:12});
        $('#tp').timepickr().timepickr({convention:12});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function add_next_row(e, row_a) {

    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        e.returnValue = false;
    }
    curr_row = $(row_a).prev('p');
    var $datefield = $('<input class="datepicker" name="sugg_date[]" type="text" value="" />').datepicker();
    var $timefield = $('<input class="timepickr" name="sugg_time[]" type="text" value="" />');
    curr_row.append($datefield);
    curr_row.append($timefield);
    curr_row.append("<br/>");


    $(".timepickr").timepickr().timepickr({convention:12});


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise the `datepicker` and `timepicker` for each new element you add. Try this:

```
function add_next_row(e, row_a) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $datefield = $('<input class="datepicker" name="sugg_date[]" type="text" value="" />').datepicker();
    var $timefield = $('<input class="tp" name="sugg_time[]" type="text" value="" />').timepickr({convention:12}); 

    curr_row = $(row_a).prev('p');
    curr_row.append($datefield);
    curr_row.append($timefield);
}
```

Comment: thank @rory it's work now for the day "the frist filed" but stranglly not working fot the time"the second filed" .

Comment: I noticed you called the plugin `timepickr` is that right, or should it be `timepicker`?

Comment: no it's right because the first filed before the append works fine

Comment: is there any other way to solve this problem i tried as hard as i can but the timepicker didn't work and i don't know why?  Rory McCrossan